# NSOpenPanel set initial selection

Tags: swift, properties, nsopenpanel

When I call NSOpenPanel, the last selection is shown. But I want to set it by my own on an initial folder. How can I do it?
Usualy I'm starting like this:

```
    let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
    openPanel.showsHiddenFiles        = false
    openPanel.canChooseDirectories    = true
```

There must me a property to set a folder or string, correct?

Comment: let panel: NSOpenPanel = NSOpenPanel();
panel.directoryURL = some URL

Comment: Excellent. Works fine. Thank you!